# iOS Simulator Custom Location issues

Tags: ios, swift, location, ios-simulator

I am having issues with the iOS simulator and specifically the custom location setting for the iPhone. When I run the app the first time the simulator is opened it finds the location of the user without issues, however if I then change the custom location, and run the app again it gives the same location as the first time, despite having changed the custom location. If instead I set the Debug> Location > none in the simulator, and change the location in Product > Schemes > Edit Schemes in xCode itself, I have no issues. However *every* time I change the location this way I have to first set the location to none in the simulator. Is it a problem with my code, or just a quirk of the simulator that I wouldn't find with a real iPhone?

```vb
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
var userLocationCity : String!
var userLocationDate : String!
var safeUsername : String!
class TinderViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate    {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geopoint: PFGeoPoint!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            println(geopoint)

            var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = geopoint.longitude
            var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = geopoint.latitude

            var location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) //changed!!!
            println(location)
            var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
            userLocationDate = stringDate

            println(userLocationDate)

            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    println("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                if placemarks.count > 0 {
                    println(userLocationCity)
                    let pm = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                    println(pm.locality)

                    println(userLocationCity)
                    userLocationCity = pm.locality
                    println(userLocationCity)
                    user["location"] = userLocationCity
                    user.save()

                    let string1 = PFUser.currentUser().objectId
                    let string2 = "ID_"
                    safeUsername = string2 + string1

                    var locate = PFObject(className: safeUsername)
                    locate.setObject(userLocationCity, forKey: "location")
                    locate.setObject(userLocationDate, forKey: "date")
                    locate.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                        if success == true {
                            println("Score created with ID: \(locate.objectId)")
                        } else {
                            println(error)
                        }                       
                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
                }
            })

           // user["location"] = geopoint
           // user.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like the issue is that you are using two different methods to simulate location. You should choose either to simulate location via schemes *or* via the debug menu in XCode, but not through both. It sounds like you're doing both, and the setting in the debug menu is overriding the setting in your scheme.

I would *strongly* advise you, however, to test any location based code on an actual device. Most of the problems that you will find with location services will not appear on the simulator; you really need to deal with the actual peculiarities of real-world GPS hardware.